# Difference between "pub use" and "pub mod"?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have this file hierarchy in a Rust package:

```
src/...
src/m1/mod.rs
src/m1/path/m2.rs
```

What would be the practical difference between having the line:

```
pub mod path::m2;
```

in my file `m1/mod.rs`, versus having the line:

```
pub use path::m2;
```

Trying to refresh my understanding of Rust after a time away, so this isn't my first learning cycle. (Of course, for other readers it may be.) I'm saying this    because I'm not asking for a general explanation of the differences between `use` and `mod`. My unclarity is specific to the two directives above. It seems like they would both serve to make the module in file `src/m1/path/m2.rs` available to the module `m1` and to anything else that imported it (because of the `pub` prefix on both directives). Is that right? Would these be perfect aliases, or would there be some differences? Is either idiom preferable to the other?

Comment: The Book explains it pretty well between the [Modules Quick Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#modules-quick-reference) and [Bringing Paths into Scope with the `use` Keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword). Does that help clarify at all?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMeadows. Do this exhaust the differences?: Only the `mod` statement requests the compilation of the `m2.rs` file.

Comment: I don't know how the compiler handles modules technically, but I think you can interpret it that way, since `mod` typically uses the file structure to bring code into scope. And yeah, you can't `use m2` if it hasn't been brought in by a `mod m2` somewhere else (although that `mod` may be in another crate, and not something you've written yourself).

Comment: Note that you don't need to have a separate file for a module. `mod child { module contents here }`

Comment: `pub mod path::m2` is not valid Rust.

Answer (score 3):

`mod foo;` is akin to copying and pasting a module into the current scope. That is, if the current scope can find module `foo` at its own "top level" — basically, if there's a file `foo.rs` or a folder `foo` in the same directory — then `mod foo;` basically gets transformed into `mod foo { /* contents of foo */ }`. Note that the [syntax for `mod`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html) requires that the thing after `mod` be an identifier, not an arbitrary path (so `mod path::m2;` would be illegal). I can only assume that modules that *could* be brought into scope aren't *automatically* brought into scope in order to limit the amount of work the compiler has to do when resolving names.

Meanwhile, once a container of items — whether that be a module, type, trait, etc — has been made available in the current scope, shortcuts to its items can be created with `use path::to::item`. If containers of items were ordinary variables, this would be akin to something like `let item = path.to.item`, if that were legal.

Answer (score 3):

I'll edit this answer later to give a fuller explanation. But, with help from the comments and other answer posted here, plus some experimentation, I think I've come to a better understanding of these directives. There may be circumstances where one *could* use either `pub use` or `pub mod`, though they'd be contrived and in any case where both could work one should prefer the former (see third point below). The key differences are:

1. `pub use` is followed by a path (a bare identifier `m2` would be the same as `self::m2`). `pub mod` is only followed by an identifier.

   `pub mod m2;` in `main.rs` or `lib.rs` would include the contents of file `./m2.rs` (or `./m2/mod.rs`). If the line `pub mod m2;` is instead in a file `path/m1.rs` (or `path/m1/mod.rs`) then the included file would instead be `path/m1/m2.rs` (or `path/m1/m2/mod.rs`).

   (You could include a module from another location using `mod m2 { include!("path/m2.rs") }` but this isn't idiomatic. I've also seen some attribute tricks that affect the location of the loaded module. But generally things work as described in the previous paragraph.)
2. The `use` directive doesn't request/order the compilation of any additional files. A `mod` directive is needed to do that.

   (In fact the additional files aren't compiled separately, but merged into the source file where the `mod` directive occurs. Only the files that are crate roots (plus whatever is merged into them) get compiled.)
3. If one file in your crate had a `pub mod m2;` line, then another file could conceivably have a choice of also using `pub mod` or `pub use`. Subject to the constraints imposed by point 1 above.

   But if you were in such circumstances, you wouldn't want to use the `mod` directive, as that would merge the relevant code into your source tree a second time. Perhaps the compiler might eventually undo the duplication, but what would you gain by hoping for that?

   There's also this statement from the "[Separating Modules into Different Files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html)" chapter in the book:

   > Note that you only need to load the contents of a file using a mod declaration once somewhere in your module tree. Once the compiler knows the file is part of the project (and knows where in the module tree the code resides because of where you’ve put the mod statement), other files in your project should refer to the code in that file using a path to where it was declared...

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the practical difference between having the line:
>
> > `pub mod path::m2;`

this is an error syntax,Rust don't allow use mod `path+::+file name`,it allow follow file name or dir name with same parent dir(in this situation,it will search `mod.rs` at sub-dir ).

`pub mod foo` means search file named foo or dir which named foo and contained `mod.rs`,then put foo's code into here.

But if you add `pub` prefix,the foo's code not only can be public in where write `pub mod`,but also can be public at parent file.

> `pub use path::m2;`

As I known,this code add module m2 in current file namespace,this is closer to your `alias`